# Sourcesafe get by label from Visual Studio

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have a Visual Source Safe repository, and some (not all, alas!) of my releases are identified by label.  I know how to get by label from the command line, but:

Can I get by label **from within Visual Studio**?

I'm using Visual Studio 2003 (would the answer be different in other versions of Visual Studio?).

Thanks.

PS.  I am hoping to migrate to Team Server soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View History on the sourcesafe Project in question, and Include Labels.  Highlight the Label you want and click "Get."  set options, hit OK, you're done!

edit: pardon me AJ, I was referring to doing a "get" on a label from within the Visual Source Safe interface.

However, assuming you have installed Visual Source Safe on the same machine as Visual Studio, these same functions should be available.  Go to Tools -> Options > Source Control and make sure the source control plug-in is set to Microsoft Visual SourceSafe.

With that in place, you should be able to right-click on a Project or Solution in the Solution Explorer, select View History, and follow my previous instructions.

Comment: I don't think I can do that from within Visual Studio?  If I can, then please leave an edit telling me how.  Thanks.

Comment: AJ - Also consider that any destroyed files will still be destroyed -- even if you get them by label, they're gone.  And FWIW, if you just need source control, go with Subversion.  It costs $0 and is >>better<<.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I would love to use svn, but I work for The Man. :(

Comment: I think this is the nearest I'm going to get.  Thanks for your answer, Barry.  :)